# How to mount or unmount all partitions of a device at once using udisksctl?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, mount, unmount, udisks

I need to use `udisksctl`.
I tried the classic method `/dev/sda?*` already seen on the internet:

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda?*
```

or

```
udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sda?*
```

`/dev/sda?*` in my case is equivalent to `/dev/sda1 /dev/sda2`

but `udisksctl` only mounts or unmounts the first partition listed `/dev/sda1`.
How can I make it mount or unmount all partitions at once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way you can do it is to loop though the `/dev/sd` device partitions

```
for i in /dev/sd??*; do udiskctl unmount -b $i; done
```

If you only wanted to do `/dev/sda` partitions then change the first `?` to `a`

```
for i in /dev/sda?*; do udiskctl unmount -b $i; done
```

Comment: I am only interested in partitions on the `/dev/sda` disk and not partitions on all `/dev/sd?` disks.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo Updated for just drive `/dev/sda`

Comment: Does this also work for `/dev/sda10`, `/dev/sda11`, `/dev/sda12`, `/dev/sda147`, `/dev/sda385`, `/dev/sda2706`, etc.?

Comment: Is good `/dev/sda?*` as in the question?

Comment: @MarioPalumbo Yeah, that should work.  :)  Updated, and I tested as well.  :)